# Radiation heat transfer

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation

I'm looking at the radiosity equations for heat transfer

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiosity_(heat_transfer)#Radiosity_method

Specifically, I'm hesitant to accept the equation:

$$ \dot Q_i = \frac{ A_i \epsilon_i }{ 1 - \epsilon_i } ( \sigma T_i^4 - J_i )$$

My analysis is as follows: power goes out via Stefan-Boltzmann term, which is given by a term like

$$ - A_i \epsilon_i \sigma T_i^4 $$

and radiation goes in via absorption of all emissions from nearby surfaces, that is:

$$ A_i \epsilon_i H_i = A_i \epsilon_i \sum_j F_{ij} J_j $$

where the radiosity $J_j$ expression is correct on the article, and we are assuming [Kirchoff's law of thermal radiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_law_of_thermal_radiation) to hold. But the above implies that the actual expression for the net heat transfer is:

$$ \dot Q_i = - A_i \epsilon_i ( \sigma T_i^4  -  H_i ) = - A_i \epsilon_i ( \sigma T_i^4  - \sum_j F_{ij} J_j ) $$

Thoughts? Is my derivation correct, or is the one on the article?